# Why when a constructor has a reference to string does not printed correctly?

Tags: c++, string, reference, c++17, stdmove

I have the following code and it does not print the correct string when its destructor is called

```
struct Tracer {

 Tracer( const std::string& name_in)
 : name{ name_in } {
  std::cout << name << " constructed.\n";
 }

~Tracer() {
 std::cout << name << " destructed.\n";
}

private:

const std::string& name;
};

Tracer static_tracer{ "static Tracer" };

int main() {

}
```

Output:
static Tracer constructed.

�1�Q�

But the following code works as expected:

```
Tracer( std::string name_in)
 : name{ std:move(name_in) } {
 std::cout << name << " constructed.\n";
 }

private:
std::string name;
```

Output:
static Tracer constructed.

static Tracer destructed.

Or when a stringview or simple stings are used.

How did we lost the reference to the string during the program termination in the first code?

Also shouldn't we loose the reference to the string using the move() since it has a constructor scope?

Thanks!

Comment: Because that's how C++ works. A temporary gets constructed, a reference to the temporary gets stored, the temporary gets destroyed; finally an attempt is made to dereference the now-garbage reference, and hillarity ensues. Your C++ book should have many chapters that discuss the fine points of references, and scope lifetimes. This is a large subject, that cannot be fully explained in one or two paragraphs on stackoverflow.com, and you will have to be referred to your textbook for all the details.

Comment: if you want a `std::string` then use a `std::string`. References are useful when you want to refer to some other object. No offense, but the problem here is that you dont know yourself what the member refers to

Comment: ...simply put: `const std::string& name;` -> `const std::string name;`

Comment: Doesn't even have to be `const std::string name;`. The member is your own. It can be non-const if you like.

Comment: Note that a "reference" in C++ is not the same thing as a "reference" in languages like Java (and many others).

Comment: try `using namespace std::string_literals; Tracer static_tracer{ "static Tracer"s };`

Comment: @idclev463035818 No offence but I know exactly what a member refers to, also you mean a std::string object is not an object?

Comment: @stelios maybe you misread my comment. The thing is: If you knew what the member reference refers to you would already know why it cannot work (as explained in the answer). You seem to insist in a comment on the answer, but I can assure you that the answer is correct

Comment: @stelios "also you mean a std::string object is not an object?" no i didnt say anything like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you can't have a string reference (`std::string const&`) to a `const char[14]`, i.e. `"static Tracer"`.

To make it work, C++ invents a temporary object `std::string{"static Tracer"}`. This object will live until your constructor returns, *but not any longer*. The constructor for `static_tracer` returns before `main` begins. And obviously the destructor also runs after the constructor returns.

Comment: But it is declared as const the reference... Also the destructor is called after the main, specifically after the whole program is terminated since it is initialized as global and not immediately after the constructor

Comment: @stelios the only `std::string` instance is the temporary. Sometimes temporaries get their lifetime prolonged by binding to a const reference (are you refering to that?), this isnt the case here

Comment: Lifetime extension is irrelevant here. It makes the temporary last as long as the reference, but "the reference" here would be the `const std::string& name_in` in the constructor argument list, and **not** `Tracer::name`.

Comment: @MSalters Yes you are correct, I missed the part where const std::string& name_in is actually a temporary object and this is the object that the member name points to. It make sense now. I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @stelios: C++ has very specific meanings for certain words. "Object' is one of them. `const std::string& name_in` is a _reference to_ an on object, and in your case to an unnamed temporary object. But a reference itself is not an object. And as your question shows, getting it slightly wrong can lead to unexpected effects, so I try to be precise.